# Map vanishes after defining new height

Tags: here-api

i am currently trying to integrate a responsive map on my website, which i built with WIX code.
I am basically starting off with the code provided by Here maps to create an interactive map (**https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/maps/map-at-specified-location**).
I integrated the code into the html iframe and it works without any problems. But as soon as i want to define the height (for responsive matters), the map vanishes and will only return if i type in the div height in px.

I am not that much of a talent when it comes to coding but i am trying really hard to get this stuff done.

Best regards,

Daud

Comment: You mean when you add height to iframe?

Comment: Sudharsan Nair, yes sort of. The height of the "div" is given in that code and as soon as i change that, the map image disappears.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the map to resize accordingly to container or window resize, make sure to have a handler for this:

```
// Window resize handler
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    map.getViewPort().resize();
});
```

Note: The variable `map` refers to your initialized HERE map object, normally to be found where the line `new H.Map(...)` is called.

Comment: Michael P. Bazos, thank you for that hint. I added that to the code but it seems that the information in the div-passage is always "preffered" by the system.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I just found a piece of sytle.css within Here Maps that helped me out with the responive div. It seems as long as there is a certain px number added to the div, the content may only be partial responsive. Obviously somehow but still complicated...

Thanks for your interest and help, guys!